# Display import data with spreadjs using web app

Tags: spreadjs

I am trying to display a table that has the following format but I don't know how to spread the columns out. The data is obtained through a json string with one column / object called vectors. The item vectors is an array of objects called “vector” that I want to display as rows with their id and data “object” which yet another an array  of items.  The json string looks as follows:

```
vectors: [ {vector: {id: "value1", data: { key1: "value", key2 : "value", ...}}}, {vector: {id: "value2", data: { key1: "value", key2 : "value", ...}}}, ...]
```

We are currently using an ELN/LIMS web application that has SpreadJS version 16.1.4 running. The data source is loaded successfully within the web app showing all the columns  including the one called “ vectors”.  Not sure how to use the web app to further display each vector as a row with their data.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Tried setting the column to an array or object and checked the checkbox “spread”.  This only added new column with the index.  Want the array of vectors as rows with a new column called  id and data.  Then the data column should be able to spread further with its properties to columns.

Comment: This is basically a table within a table where I am trying to display the inner table